# std::sort в С++ работает на одном процессоре или распараллеливается?

Tags: c++, сортировка, std

`std::sort` в С++ работает на одном процессоре или распараллеливается?

Comment: Это сообщество на русском языке, английский перевод был не нужен: я его удалил.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520720/c-parallel-sort

Answer (score 11):

В С++17 появилась новая функция `sort`:

```
template< class ExecutionPolicy, class RandomIt >
void sort( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

Параметр `policy` отвечает за политику выполнения.
Также в С++17 появился новый заголовочный файл `execution`, в котором нахдятся классы и обьекты, которые можно передавать в `sort`.
Вот ссылки, для более детального ознакомления:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t

---

Немного тестов:
Для сравнения запустим `sort` без параметра `policy`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "Creating vec...\n";
    vector<int> vec(100'000'000);

    cout << "Initializing vec...\n";
    generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rand);

    cout << "Start sorting...\n";
    clock_t start = clock();
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << "Sorting time: " << double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " secs.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Creating vec...
Initializing vec...
Start sorting...
Sorting time: 10.313 secs.
```

Теперь заменим вызов на `sort(execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end());`
И получим вывод:

```
Sorting time: 4.795 secs.
```

Answer (score 8):

По умолчанию - на одном.

Если написать `std::sort(std::execution::par, ...);` или `std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, ...);`, то [по идее](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) должен распараллелиться. На практике не проверял.

Comment: На Visual Studio проверял - распараллеливается. По крайней мере, работает быстрее.

Comment: @Mikhailo на Linux надо подцепить libtbb-dev (TBB)